# Uniformly convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(x)}{(x+1)^n} $

Tags: real-analysis

I have found thai the  series pointwise converges in E =$(-\infty,-2); [0,+\infty)$ .
To study the uniformly convergence I calculate the sum of the series for x>0 and it's not continuous in zero so there isn't uniformly convergence in $[0,+\infty)$.But can I have in $(0,+\infty)?$

Comment: Interestingly, the series converges to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0 <x<1$ we have (using the formula for a geometric sum)  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac x {(1+x)^{n}}=1-\frac 1 {(1+x)^{N}}$. If the  series converges uniformly then $\frac 1 {(1+x)^{N}}$ must tend to $0$ uniformly.  Taking $x=\frac  1 N$ we see that this is not true. Hence the series does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: For $(-\infty,-2)$?

Comment: @GiulyB A very similar argemuent  shows that the convergence is  not uniform on $(-\infty, -2)$. Here you have to choose $x=-\frac 1 n -2$ at the end.